# quantmod - Quarterly and Annual reports - Is it possible to extract past 10 historic periods?

Tags: r, quantmod

Is there way I can extract the data for last 10 historic periods?
As of now I am getting 5 historic quarterly reports and 4 historic Annual reports via this code.

Please help me.

```
library(quantmod)
getFin('AAPL') # returns AAPL.f to "env"
viewFin(AAPL.f, "IS", "Q") # Quarterly Income Statement
viewFin(AAPL.f, "CF", "A") # Annual Cash Flows
```

Comment: That is because Google Finance, data source restricts output for last 5 years see [here](http://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3AAAPL&fstype=ii)

Comment: That is make sense. Thank you. Is there any other package I use to get more data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW, if you want 10 years worth of metrics and ratios, you can use this methodology.

```
read.csv("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&t=AAPL",header=T,stringsAsFactors = F,skip = 2)[,-c(12)]->spreadsheet
#str(spreadsheet)
View(spreadsheet)
```

Comment: Seems like this query is giving me Annual reports. Is there a way I get quarterly data? please help.

Comment: I looked here: 
https://gist.github.com/hahnicity/45323026693cdde6a116

I didn't see any quarterly data.  Do you have a URL that has the data you need?

Comment: In this example, I got last 5 quarters. Nice if I get more...http://financials.morningstar.com/income-statement/is.html?t=mck&ops=clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, but I think the limitation is 4 years of historical data.

```
require(quantmod)

setwd("C:/Users/your_path_here/Desktop")

stocks <- c("AAVL",
"ACAD",
"ACHN")

# equityList <- read.csv("EquityList.csv", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# names(equityList) <- c ("Ticker")

for (i in 1 : length(stocks)) {   
        temp<-getFinancials(stocks[i],src="google",auto.assign=FALSE)
        write.csv(temp$IS$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Income_Statement(Annual).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$BS$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Balance_Sheet(Annual).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$CF$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Cash_Flow(Annual).csv",sep=""))
}
```

Comment: It looks like you need to pay for a premium membership for 10 quarters of data.

Comment: Is there way I get Quarterly reports from user 7075507? All I am getting annual data and I like to get qurterly data as well.